# Do I really need to setup a mongrel cluster to handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, mongrel-cluster, refinerycms

So my father runs a rather small business. I'm going to set him up with a website using RefineryCMS (that's a ror-based cms).. He will probably get less than 500 hits a month. Do I really need to set up mongrel cluster for this as about every tutorial on the web suggests?

Does anyone some good reading material for setting up a simple, small scale RoR-production environment? I want to move away from apache and try nginx or lighttpd as the server. What would be YOUR preferred setup for a site that will get between 100 and 500 hits a month?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer is Passenger.  If you know Apache, use it, otherwise use Nginx.  It's a piece of cake to setup, and manages the processes for you.  It's pretty much like setting up a PHP site.  [Here's a link](http://www.modrails.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I know apache but this is a good opportunity for me to learn a little more about other options. I'll try passenger and nginx.

Comment: You can use Phusion Passenger with Apache as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could host such a setup on heroku.com free stack and not have to worry about setting up your own server.

We even have a tutorial: http://tutorials.refinerycms.org/tutorials/how-to-install-refinery-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Even easier to run: [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/). But probably needs nginx too to handle slow connections (over the internet).

Comment: I'd consider Passenger easier to use than Unicorn any day.  I do use unicorn though because it seems faster, and support UNIX sockets with nginx, among other things like hot code reloading.  Doesn't sound like the OP needs any of that ;)

Comment: Probably `screen` + `unicorn_rails` to get it running is only my definition of easy ;-)

Comment: Since Phusion Passenger 3 you can just do `screen` + `passenger start`; it'll even automatically spin down unused processes for you to save RAM and you can directly attach it to port 80, something you can't do with Unicorn.

Phusion Passenger also supports Unix sockets and hot code reloading. It has done that since version 1.0. Heck, with Phusion Passenger you can't *not* use Unix sockets.